# Using mysql concat() in WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to search my table having a column of first names and a column of last names.  I currently accept a search term from a field and compare it against both columns, one at a time with

```
    select * from table where first_name like '%$search_term%' or 
    last_name like '%$search_term%';
```

This works fine with single word search terms but the result set includes everyone with the name "Larry". But if someone enters a first name then a space, then a last name, I want a narrower search result. I've tried the following without success.

```
    select * from table where first_name like '%$search_term%' or last_name 
    like '%$search_term%' or concat_ws(' ',first_name,last_name) 
    like '%$search_term%';
```

Any advice?

**EDIT:**  The name I'm testing with is "Larry Smith".  The db stores "Larry" in the "first_name" column, and "Smith" in the "last_name" column.  The data is clean, no extra spaces and the search term is trimmed left and right.

**EDIT 2:**  I tried Robert Gamble's answer out this morning.  His is very similar to what I was running last night.  I can't explain it, but this morning it works.  The only difference I can think of is that last night I ran the concat function as the third "or" segment of my search query (after looking through first_name and last_name). This morning I ran it as the last segment after looking through the above as well as addresses and business names.

Does running a mysql function at the end of a query work better than in the middle?

Comment: I just ran the version you were having trouble with and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

What you have should work but can be reduced to:

```
select * from table where concat_ws(' ',first_name,last_name) 
like '%$search_term%';
```

Can you provide an example name and search term where this doesn't work?

Comment: Is this syntax or something similar supported by all databases? Is it mentioned in the SQL standard?

Comment: Is there some way of doing this, albeit differently in all databases?

Comment: How about doing this one in 2 different tables? My situation is in different tables, that's why.

Comment: Do you know if this query can use indexes?

Answer (score 14):

Note that the search query is now case sensitive.

When using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `first_name` LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

It will match both "Larry" and "larry". With this concat_ws, it will suddenly become case sensitive!

This can be fixed by using the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', `first_name`, `last_name`) LIKE UPPER('%$search_term%')
```

Edit: Note that this only works on non-binary elements. See also [mynameispaulie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13184217/1201863).

Comment: In case you are concatening integer fields the case sensitivity can also be a result of a bug in MySQL before version 5.5 - see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397156/why-concat-does-not-default-to-default-charset-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *,concat_ws(' ',first_name,last_name) AS whole_name FROM users HAVING whole_name LIKE '%$search_term%'
```

...is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4):

To Luc:

I agree with your answer, although I would like to add that UPPER only works on non-binary elements. If you are working with say an AGE column (or anything numeric) you will need to perform a CAST conversion to make the UPPER function work correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name, CAST(age AS CHAR)) LIKE UPPER('%$search_term%');
```

Forgive me for not responding to Luc's answer directly but for the life of me I could not figure out how to do that. If an admin can move my post, please do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Leaving comments requires [50 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Yes, it's annoying for visitors with something helpful to add, but it also cuts down on irrelevant chatter. Posting what should be a comment as an answer is frowned upon in any case, but since you've provided information relevant to solving the problem it's probably fine.

Comment: Fifty is quite a high limit :/ Anyway, I upvoted your answer (+10 rep) and linked to it in my post. Thanks for the addition :)

Comment: In case you are concatening integer fields the case sensitivity can also be a result of a bug in MySQL before version 5.5 - see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397156/why-concat-does-not-default-to-default-charset-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

you can do that (work in mysql) probably other SQL too..
just try this:

```
select * from table where concat(' ',first_name,last_name) 
    like '%$search_term%';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that could get in the way - is your data clean?

It could be that you have spaces at the end of the first name field, which then means you have two spaces between the firstname and lastname when you concat them? Using trim(first_name)/trim(last_name) will fix this - although the real fix is to update your data.

You could also this to match where two words both occur but not necessarily together (assuming you are in php - which the $search_term variable suggests you are)

```
$whereclauses=array();
$terms = explode(' ', $search_term);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
    $whereclauses[] = "CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) LIKE '%$term%'";
}
$sql = "select * from table where";
$sql .= implode(' and ', $whereclauses);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

```
select * FROM table where (concat(first_name, ' ', last_name)) = $search_term;
```

Comment: You'll have to add brackets to your '$search_term'

Comment: This also requires the user to input the name exactly instead of partial matches (example: 'Pat' matches 'Pat' and 'Patrick')