# Compare value with concatenated fields in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Say I want to search for a user, 'Richard Best'. Is it possible to compare the full name is concatenated first name and last name? I do not have  a full name field.

```
select * from users where last_name + ' ' + first_name like '%richa%'
```

I am using Mysql

Comment: There's got to be a better way to check...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using mysql concat() in WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303679/using-mysql-concat-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These are equivalent:

```
select * from users where concat(last_name,' ',first_name) like '%richa%'

select * from users where concat_ws(' ',last_name,first_name) like '%richa%'
```

This might also work:

```
select * from users where last_name like '%richa%' or first_name like '%richa%'
```

Comment: Two propositions are not equivalent :

With "Richard Gasquet", the search with "Richard G" won't work with your second solution because "Richard G" doesn't match firstname nor lastname !

Comment: @Nico401 I have no idea what you're talking about. I stand by my claim that `concat(A,' ',B)` `concat_ws(' ',A,B)` are equivalent.  If, on the other hand, you're trying to match `like '%Richard G%'` using the non-concat syntax, well then that's not going to work too well, duh.

Comment: I'm ok for concat and concat_ws equivalence. But concatenation and your third proposition (with OR) are not equivalent. If you write the lastname and a part of the firstname, concat solution will work although the OR solution won't.

Comment: The answer is in two sections.  Section one: "These are equivalent".  Section two: "This might also work".  There was never any suggestion that section two is equivalent to section one.

Comment: It works in some precise cases, but I agree with you so. Take my post as a precision.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this thread.

[Using mysql concat() in WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303679/using-mysql-concat-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from users where (first_name + ' ' + last_name) like '%richa%'
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel Eloquent you can use `whereRaw("concat(first_name,' ',last_name) LIKE %$search%")`