# Why CONCAT() does not default to default charset in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, perl, utf-8

What is the reason, that using CONCAT() in pure UTF-8 environment MySQL still treats concatenated string (when some col in expression is for example int or date) as some other charset (probably Latin-1)?

MySQL environment seen from client (`\s`):

```
Server characterset:    utf8
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
```

Test dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE `utf8_test` ( 
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    `title` varchar(50) collate utf8_estonian_ci default NULL,
    `year` smallint(4) unsigned NOT NULL default '0', 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_estonian_ci;

INSERT INTO utf8_test VALUES (1, 'Õäöüšž', 2011);
```

This query is good:

```
SELECT id, title FROM utf8_test;
```

This one turns utf-8 flag off (already in MySQL, AFIU):

```
SELECT CONCAT(id, title) FROM utf8_test;
```

From mysql-client everything seems fine, because it is set to show chars as UTF-8, but when running through perl DBI, all results of queries having CONCAT() inside don't have utf-8 flag set. Example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8::all;
use Encode qw(is_utf8);

my $dbh = your_db_connect_routine('test');

my $str = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT CONCAT(id, title) FROM utf8_test');
print "CONCAT: False\n" unless ( is_utf8($str) );

my $str = $dbh->selectrow_array('SELECT title FROM utf8_test');
print "NO CONCAT: False\n" unless ( is_utf8($str) );
```

There is at least two workarounds i know

- quering with CAST() `SELECT CONCAT( CAST(id AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8), title) FROM utf8_test`
- using `$str = Encode::_utf8_on($str)` (is considered as bad practice?)

but i am asking: why it is in MySQL so? Should i consider it as bug or feature?

Comment: What happens in other clients besides Perl DBI? For example, a MySQL GUI tool or some other language? Also have you tried an alternate driver such as `DBD::Wire10`

Comment: @Dan: `DBD::Wire10` had same behaviour. But works right in Python. Still problem in DBI?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a well known bug in MySQL. It's fixed in MySQL 5.5

See: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=12030

The issue stems from concatenating an integer with a varchar.

The work around is to cast the id (integer) first to a char, and then concatenate, 
ie:

```
SELECT CONCAT(cast(id as char), title) FROM utf8_test
```

Comment: Not only integers, but also timestamps cause the problem. Thanks for the workaround! +1

Comment: Timestamps are anyway already stored as INTs so if you handle all INT columns, it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is DBD::mysql issue/peculiarity. Try enabling utf8 in database handle as described in [POD](http://search.cpan.org/~capttofu/DBD-mysql-4.011/lib/DBD/mysql.pm) for `DBD::mysql` (`mysql_enable_utf8` part).

This old (Perl 5.8 times) [article](http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2008/04/25/utf8_mysql_perl.php) can also help.

Comment: As i answered to Dan: same behaviour with `DBD::Wire10` driver. For `DBD::mysql` `mysql_enable_utf8` is also in connection-function. And i don't understand, how could query affect on DBI or DBD::* level?

Comment: On CentOS 7 with the vendor-supplied `perl-DBD-MySQL-4.023-6`, I still had to `$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');` (as described in the article you link to), even though my server, schema, table, and columns were all utf8, with utf8 collations. So it seems the Perl DBD::mysql client's seeming to default to "latin1" was the issue for me.