# LIKE wildcard with multiple fields and spaces in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, search, sql-like

I'm having some trouble searching for any similar match in two fields.
For example I have a table with the values:

```
CAR MAKE   CAR MODEL
Ford       Mustang (Shelby)
Toyota     Corolla
Seat       Leon

etc etc.
```

I want to be able to get the result "Ford, Mustang (Shelby)" by searching for any of the following combinations:

- Ford
- Mustang
- Shelby
- Ford Mustang

  or any other combination.

Is this possible?
I've had a good search but it's hard to find the search terms to describe what I mean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Split your terms on whitespace and then, for each term, build a little bit of SQL like this:

```
car_make like '%x%' or car_model like '%x%'
```

Then join all of those with `or` to get your WHERE clause. So for "Shelby Ford", you'd end up with SQL like this:

```
select stuff
from cars
where car_make like '%Shelby%'
   or car_model like '%Shelby%'
   or car_make like '%Ford%'
   or car_model like '%Ford%'
```

If you need anything more complicated then investigate MySQL's [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html) capabilities.

Comment: It's looking to be a bit more complicated than that but I think you're right about the full-text search, I hadn't looked into that.

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT Car_Make, Car_Model, CONCAT_WS(' ', Car_Make, Car_Model) as Make_Model 
FROM cars 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', Car_Make, Car_Model) LIKE '%Ford Mustang%'
```

Not sure of the exact syntax since I'm not at home but something similar should work.

See also: [Using mysql concat() in WHERE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303679/using-mysql-concat-in-where-clause)

Comment: Thanks, gave it a quick try but not getting anywhere. Think I'll take a closer look when I get a chance