# Search columns in two tables: ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias

Tags: mysql, sql

I get this error when attempting the query below. I have a table called access_groups, one called companies, and a join table called access_group_companies. I'm trying to run a search with AND logic using fields in companies.name and access_groups.name. Any idea what is causing this? And if you might know of a better way to run this search, that would be great.

```sql
SELECT ag.id, ag.name, c.name
FROM access_groups ag,
     companies c
         JOIN ag ON ag.id = access_group_companies.access_group_id
WHERE CONCAT(ag.name, c.name) LIKE '%ВТБ%';
```

Comment: What is the common column in `access_groups` and `companies`? Do you have `id` in `companies` table as well?

Comment: Don't mix implicit and explicit joins... Use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax everywhere. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Could you clarify regarding implicit and explicit? I thought I was just doing a generic join here

Comment: the last part should be more like "LIKE %Тест ВТБ"...this has issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what information you provided and assuming there is join column in `companies(id)` which can be joined with `access_group_companies(company_id)`.

```
SELECT ag.id, ag.name, c.name 
FROM access_groups ag 
INNER JOIN access_group_companies agc ON ag.id = agc.access_group_id 
INNER JOIN companies c ON c.id = agc.company_id
WHERE CONCAT(ag.name, c.name) LIKE '%ВТБ%';
```

Comment: This is great, but if I have more than one search term, like 'test 123', it doesn't work

Comment: The result should have something that appears in the string produced from both columns

Comment: Not sure I follow the condition you want on both the columns `ag.name` and `c.name`. May be you want `ag.name LIKE '%test 123%' OR c.name LIKE '%test 123%' `.

Comment: Yes, there may be multiple words - for ag.name or c.name

Comment: You need to split the words on whitespace and for each word add a `LIKE ` condition. `ag.name LIKE '%test%' OR ag.name LIKE '%123%' OR c.name LIKE '%test%' OR c.name LIKE '%123%'`. May be this answer is what you were looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129355/like-wildcard-with-multiple-fields-and-spaces-in-mysql

Comment: yes, that's down the right road...but can't REGEXP be used here?